# Compilation Error: "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item" while explicitly implementing the interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am getting this error while creating a `public` method on a class for explicitly implementing the `interface`. I have a workaround: by removing the explicit implementation of `PrintName` method. But I am surprised why I am getting this error.

Can anyone explain the error?

Code for Library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test.Lib1
{

    public class Customer : i1 
    {
        public string i1.PrintName() //Error Here...
        {
            return this.GetType().Name + " called from interface i1";
        }
    }

    public interface i1
    {
        string PrintName();
    }

    interface i2
    {
        string PrintName();
    }
}
```

Code for Console Test Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Test.Lib1;

namespace ca1.Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            Console.WriteLine(customer.PrintName());

            //i1 i1o = new Customer();
            //Console.WriteLine(i1o.printname());

            //i2 i2o = new Customer();
            //Console.WriteLine(i2o.printname());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

When using **explicit** implementation of an interface, the members are forced to something more restricted than **private** in the class itself. And when the access modifier is forced, you may not add one.

Likewise, in the interface itself,  all members are **public**. If you try to add a modifier inside an interface you will get a similar error.

Why are explicit members (very) private? Consider:

```
interface I1 { void M(); }
interface I2 { void M(); }

class C : I1, I2
{
    void I1.M() { ... }
    void I2.M() { ... }
}

C c = new C();
c.M();         // Error, otherwise: which one?
(c as I1).M(); // Ok, no ambiguity.
```

If those methods were public, you would have a name-clash that cannot be resolved by the normal overload rules.

For the same reason you cannot even call `M()` from inside a `class C` member. You will have to cast `this` to a specific interface first to avoid the same ambiguity.

```
class C : I1, I2
{
   ...
   void X() 
   {  
     M();             // error, which one? 
     ((I1)this).M();  // OK 
   }
}
```

Comment: (c as I1).M(); // no problem 
It is correct, but what if you want to access the method M outside the assambly, It is not accessible?

Comment: @Lalit, it is accessible everywhere I1 is accessible. Also in other assemblies.

Comment: Interface I1 is accessible outside assambly but Method M for Class C is not accessible ouuside, Check the class browser as well it is marked as private.

Comment: If I1 is accessible then it should work. If not, ask a separate question.

Comment: Score another win for VB on this front for ease of use.  A class method/property is defined and then specified as implementing a specific interface method, rather than having to implement each interface method and then provide a wrapper to expose the functionality.  I did recently move to an all C# shop from VB and am starting to notice quite a few differences when it comes to more complex programming patterns.

Answer (score 17):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx :
When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
```

`Console.WriteLine(customer.PrintName());`

Violates this

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use access modifiers when implementing interface explicitly. Member will be binded to the interface anyway, so it is no need to specify access modifier, because all interface members are always public, also all explicitly implemented members can be accessed only through member of interface type (see statichippo's answer for example).

Comment: "It is a compile-time error for an explicit interface member implementation to include access modifiers, and it is a compile-time error to include the modifiers abstract, virtual, override, or static." Relevant documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is an Explicit implementation, the default scope for the members of the interface is public, whereas it is private in case of a class, ergo, there is no need to use the Public modifier because when we call that method it would be called with the reference of the interface only.

According to "[MSDN Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)" the functions that implement explicit interfaces are never explicitly defined public. They are public by default. It would be meaningless to define them otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

When we want to go with implicit implementation for the above example, following would be the code.

```
    interface I1 { void M(); }
interface I2 { void M(); }

class C : I1, I2
{
    public void M() { ... }
}

C c = new C();
c.M();  // Ok, no ambiguity. Because both Interfaces gets implemented with one    method definition.
```