# How to call method which is explicitly implemented

Tags: c#, oop

I have a code some thing below.

```
interface IFirst
{
   void Show();
}

public class Test : IFirst
{
   void IFirst.Show()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("First");
   }
}
```

Here in the implementation class i cannot provide public access specifier for Show(). 
How can i call this Show() from main program?

Comment: `((IFirst)new Test()).Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit interfaces methods can only be accessed through the interface and not through the class that implement them.

In your code, you can cast an instance of your class to the interface and then reference the method/property that was explicitly defined.

MSDN Link on Explicit Interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Another question asking a similar thing:
[Compilation Error: "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item" while explicitly implementing the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669031/compilation-error-the-modifier-public-is-not-valid-for-this-item-while-crea)

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
IFirst obj = new Test();
obj.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your variable to Interface type, because explicit interfaces methods can only be accessed using the interface and cannot be accessed with the class that implement them. Using explicit interface implementations is a form of code encapsulation and let you hide the implementation details of your class (also allowing implementing many interfaces with conflicting methods' names).

```
Test test = new Test();
var casted = test as IFirst;
casted.Show();
```

Also you could use implicit casting sending variable to method:

```
public void ShowMeATrick(IFirst first) {
    first.Show();
}

Test test = new Test();
ShowMeATrick(test);
```