# ASP.NET Boilerplate: Unable to hit the service from index.js

Tags: javascript, aspnetboilerplate

We are trying to implement a custom service using [aspnetboilerplate](/questions/tagged/aspnetboilerplate) .NET Core Multi Page Application template. We are receiving an error in **index.js** file when trying to hit a service method.

Find herewith the code sections for understanding. Any help on this will be really helpful for us.

```
public interface IMyTaskAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<List<string>> GetMyTasks(int input);
}

public class MyTaskAppService : IMyTaskAppService
{
    private readonly IMyTaskRepository _mytaskRepository;

    public MyTaskAppService(IMyTaskRepository mytaskRepository)
    {
        _mytaskRepository = mytaskRepository;
    }

    Task<List<string>> IMyTaskAppService.GetMyTasks(int input)
    {
        return _mytaskRepository.GetMyTasks(input);
    }

}
```

[image: Error Screenshot 1]

[image: Error Screenshot 2]

[Index.Js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCWCr.jpg)

[Index.Js Error (Lowercase)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmuYG.jpg)

[Console Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RMmQ.jpg)

Comment: How is `_mytaskService` defined?

Comment: public interface IMyTaskAppService : IApplicationService
    {
        Task<List<string>> GetMyTasks(int input);
    }

Comment: public class MyTaskAppService : IMyTaskAppService
    {
        private readonly IMyTaskRepository _mytaskRepository;

        public MyTaskAppService(IMyTaskRepository mytaskRepository)
        {
            _mytaskRepository = mytaskRepository;
        }

        Task<List<string>> IMyTaskAppService.GetMyTasks(int input)
        {
            return _mytaskRepository.GetMyTasks(input);
        }

    }

Comment: That certainly isn't JavaScript. Also, edit your question instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: @RSiva How is `_mytaskService` defined in your JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks @aaron. Have edited the question & included the code

Comment: That certainly isn't JavaScript.

Comment: var _mytaskService = abp.services.app.mytask;

Comment: Added the index.js screenshot in the post

Answer (score 1):

1. `MyTaskAppService` requires at least one `public` method:

   ```cs
   public class MyTaskAppService : IMyTaskAppService
   {
       // ...

       // Task<List<string>> IMyTaskAppService.GetMyTasks(int input)
       public Task<List<string>> GetMyTasks(int input)
       {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   What you have is an [explicit implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669140/8601760) that is "more restricted than **private**".
2. Service and method names are in **camelCase** for [Client Proxies](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#client-proxies).

   Use an uppercase `T` for `myTask`:

   ```js
   var _myTaskService = abp.services.app.myTask;
   ```

   Use a lowercase `g` for `getMyTasks`:

   ```js
   _myTaskService.getMyTasks({
       taskID: taskID
   }).done(function (data) {
       alert(data);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks @aaron. Tried both. lowercase also throws the same error. I am attaching the error screenshot (lowercase) in original post.

Comment: Try `_mytaskService = abp.services.app.myTask;`

Comment: Same issue persists.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(abp.services.app)`?

Comment: We are receiving account, configuration, role, tenant, session & user objects. mytask is missing. Attached the screenshot with original post.

Comment: Looking for a  sample code (complete flow) of implementing a custom service (apart from user, session, tenant, role, account & configuration) & making calls to custom service methods via Web API. i.e abp.services.app.<customservicename>

Comment: When I make GetMyTasks method as public, I am getting an error saying "The modifier public is not valid for this item"

Comment: Remove the `IMyTaskAppService.` prefix as shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes. I have removed IMyTaskAppService as advised. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ApplicationService` as a base for your `MyTaskAppService` class.
See my code;

```
public class MyTaskAppService : ApplicationService, IMyTaskAppService
{
    private readonly IMyTaskRepository _mytaskRepository;

    public MyTaskAppService(IMyTaskRepository mytaskRepository)
    {
        _mytaskRepository = mytaskRepository;
    }

    Task<List<string>> IMyTaskAppService.GetMyTasks(int input)
    {
        return _mytaskRepository.GetMyTasks(input);
    }    
}
```

See [TaskAppService](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/SimpleTaskSystem/SimpleTaskSystem.Application/Tasks/TaskAppService.cs).

```
public interface IMyTaskAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<List<string>> GetMyTasks(int input);
}
```

See the complete source-code of [SimpleTaskSystem](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/SimpleTaskSystem)

Comment: Thanks @Alper Ebicoglu. I am using StoredProcedureDemo code from https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/tree/master/StoredProcedureDemo. WebApi project is missing in this sample code base. I am trying to use ASPNet core (Multi Page Web Application) with MVC & stored procedures. Please help.

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes. I have added ApplicationService as a base to my MyTaskAppService class as per your suggestion but still the issue persists. Should I require WebApi project & MyTaskSystemWebApiModule?