# C#8 feature used in framework 4.7.2 does NOT cause build error in Visual Studio, but does on TFS

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a C# class library for .NET Framework 4.7.2.  One of my developers added an interface, and marked some of the members as `public`, which is only supported using C# 8.  Neither his computer, nor mine, gives any error or warning about this problem, which allowed it to slip past code review.  However our TFS server threw the correct error.

The interface:

```
public interface IHintManager
{
    public void AddJoinHint(string leftTable, string rightTable, JoinHint hint);
    public void AddQueryHint(QueryHint hint);
    public void AddTableHint(string table, TableHint hint);
    void InjectHints(DbContext context, DbCommand command, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext);
}
```

.csproj is set to 4.7.2:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

The TFS Error:

[image]

Build output locally:

[image]

Why wouldn't we be seeing this error locally, and what do we need to change in order to have consistent build results between local developers and TFS in the future?

Comment: here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669031/compilation-error-the-modifier-public-is-not-valid-for-this-item-while-expl why even add `public` to the members, they are by default because it's an interface. Remove `public` and try again.

Comment: Try to add `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to your `.cspoj` file

Comment: `LangVersion` is already set to latest.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ the mentioned question is about 10 years old. OP asks about C#8

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski so what, interface member declaration hasn't changed... I guarantee removing the explicit `public` will fix the issue.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It was a mistake, and SHOULD have caused a compile error. this is what I'm trying to fix.  Visual Studio is not showing a build error on this.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Oh, I see, OP doesn't use any default implementations, just declarations. Make sense to just remove a `public` access modifier

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes :)

Comment: Yes... Obviously I know how to fix the code.  However, I want Visual Studio to show the same build error that TFS is, so that we do not run in to this problem in the future.

Comment: By default, *it should be giving a compile time error*, mine does.

Comment: I''ll bet that someone changed the project settings in the past to enable support for an earlier language version (e.g. C# 7). Check the ".csproj" file for `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` or `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` and remove it if you find it. VS2019 uses the selected .Net framework version to determine the supported C# language version unless it's overriden with the above.

Comment: @MatthewWatson read comments?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ So where in the comments does it say to REMOVE `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` ?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Read my comment again, more carefully this time. ;) I'm saying to REMOVE it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner he's *recommending to remove it* :) and of course, but then you need to still remove `public`... 
Also you can change the build arguments if you really want to specifically tell which version to compile against...

Comment: TFS version? What build's task is used?

Comment: Removing `LangVersion` did indeed cause Visual Studio to start displaying this as a build error locally.  Thank you.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone probably changed the project settings in the past (when it was a Visual Studio 2017 project) to enable support for an earlier language version (e.g. C# 7).

Check the ".csproj" file for `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` or `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` and remove it if you find it.

VS2019 uses the selected .Net framework version to determine the supported C# language version unless it's overridden with the above.

For VS2017 you could select to use the latest language version via the project settings (without editing the .CSProj file) and if you did that, after upgrading to VS2019 it would allow the use of C#8...

We hit exactly the same issue as you because of that sequence of events. We have now decided that using `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` is no longer safe, since after upgrading to a newer version of Visual Studio, you could end up accidentally enabling a later version of the C# language than you intended.

Comment: `We have now decided that using <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> is no longer safe` of course, if you are saying to use the latest, you need to conform to to that version... It's something that can be easily look *past*... Then again, *code review*, review of actual code *would have caught this*, JMHO.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Actually, the setting doesn't appear in the code. It's in the .CSProj file, and the setting could be modified via project properties using VS2017 (which is what happened) rather than via editing the .CSProj file. The mistake was that someone chose "Latest version" rather than "c# 7" in the project settings, and nobody noticed until we started using VS2019! Of course, you could argue that people should be reviewing changes to .csproj files too, but that's easily overlooked it seems.

Comment: @Mattew Watson we review *all files that are new, modified etc* for these exact reasons; it's part of our review process. Much can happen in a proj file and overlooked as you have witnessed. Glad you found the solution to it!