# How do I create a callback function for the LZMA (7zip) SDK encoder.Code() function?

Tags: c#, delegates, 7zip, lzma

Below is a small excerpt from a class I'm building for the LZMA (7zip) SDK found [here](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).  Everything seems to be working OK for the most part but I'm trying to implement some progress reporting to track the progress of the compression process.  On the line below `encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, null);` I use `null` when I need to use some form of an `ICodeProgress` callback.

I just want to create some type of delegate callback to track the progress within the thread I have created in my class.

Class Excerpt:

```
public class CompressorThreads : CompressorClassEvents
{
    public static class SevenZipCoderProperties
    {
        public static readonly CoderPropID[] PropertyNames =
        {
            CoderPropID.DictionarySize,
            CoderPropID.PosStateBits,
            CoderPropID.LitContextBits,
            CoderPropID.LitPosBits,
            CoderPropID.Algorithm,
            CoderPropID.NumFastBytes,
            CoderPropID.MatchFinder,
            CoderPropID.EndMarker,
        };

        public static readonly object[] PropertyValues =
        {
            (Int32)LzmaDictionarySize.VerySmall,
            (Int32)(2),
            (Int32)(3),
            (Int32)(0),
            (Int32)(2),
            (Int32)LzmaSpeed.Fastest,
            "bt4",
            true,
        };
    }


    private void Compress(string filePath, string compressedFilePath)
    {
        //Get the bytes of the file
        byte[] fileInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        //Setup the encoder
        SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder encoder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder();
        encoder.SetCoderProperties(SevenZipCoderProperties.PropertyNames, SevenZipCoderProperties.PropertyValues);

        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.WriteCoderProperties(outStream);

            //Get the file bytes into a memory then compress them
            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(fileInBytes))
            {
                long uncompressedFilesize = inStream.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                        outStream.WriteByte((Byte)(uncompressedFilesize >> (8 * i)));

                encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, null);
            }

            //Write the compressed file
            compressedFileSize = outStream.Length;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(compressedFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                outStream.WriteTo(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the declaration of the you class that contains your Compress function.

Comment: @JimRhodes done.  I edited the question to also remove all the inline delegate junk I wrote in the question.  I edited your answer to reflect my questions new information you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICodeProgress is an inteface so you need to implement it somewhere. You can implement the ICodeProgress interface in your class and pass `this` instead of `null`.

For example, you would do something like this:

```
class CompressorThreads : CompressorClassEvents, ICodeProgress
{
    void ICodeProgress.SetProgress(long inSize, long outSize)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("processedInSize:" + inSize + "  processedOutSize:" + outSize);
    }
    private void Compress(string filePath, string compressedFilePath)
    {
        . . .
        encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, this);
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh!  Nice!  I'll give that a shot.  Didn't realize that's how you use interfaces.  Thanks!

Comment: That looks like it did the trick, now compiles.  Followup question, Is there an `access modifier` I can use on the SetProgress callback function?  Nothing I seem to try and use works, ex: `public`, `internal`, `protected`, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I believe it needs to be `public`.

Comment: It says no.  :)  `The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item`.  It seems to only like there being NO modifier.  :(

Comment: You also need to make the class `public` or `internal`.

Comment: I made the class and everything referencing it `internal` (like your example).  Then tried to make the callback `public` or `internal` and neither would compile.

Comment: You need to omit the modifier. There is an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669140/798346